# How to plot multiple distributions with ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

[image: ggplot image]

I plotted this trying to understand how to plot the distribution of each singular feature of my dataframe. So, trying to understand if my procedure was correct I implemented this code to plot rapidly two features.

```
New <- c(Carm[,3],Carm[,4])
Names <-names(Carm)
Label <-c(Names[1],Names[2])
dat <- data.frame(New)

names(dat)[1] <- Label[1]
names(dat)[2] <- Label[2]
dat <- stack(dat) #I built a new smaller db taking only two features
# Now I use ggplot
ggplot(dat, aes(x=values)) + 

geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.5, color = "black",fill ="white")  +

geom_density(aes(group=ind, colour=ind, fill=ind), alpha=0.2)    +

facet_wrap( ~ ind, ncol=2)
```

So, my question is : why the densities are so small if compared to the histograms? How can I fix it?

Comment: Because the histograms are plotting counts, not densities. Try `geom_histogram(aes(y=..density..), etc)`

Comment: Indeed, as Rui says. Alternatively you can do `geom_density(aes(y = after_stat(count * 0.5)))`. The 0.5 being the binwidth of your histogram.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To plot a density histogram, it needs to be told not to plot counts. This is done mapping the aesthetic `y = ..density..`. See section *Computed variables* in `help('geom_histogram')`. I will use built-in data set `iris` as the example data set.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(dat, aes(values)) +
  geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density..), bins = 20, color = "black", fill ="white") +
  geom_density(aes(fill = ind), alpha = 0.2) +
  facet_wrap(~ ind)
```

[image]

**Data**

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

iris[iris$Species == "virginica", 3:4] %>% 
  pivot_longer(everything(), 
               names_to = "ind", 
               values_to = "values") -> dat
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because while geom_histogram plots counts per bin, while geom density scales the data and represents what proportion of the data is per bin